# How to organize C++ dependent projects in github?

Tags: c++, git, github

I have two projects which I want to keep in separate repositories.
Project A is a large project, and project B is a small tool that was at first part of project A.

So the thing is project A needs some of the functions of project B, and project B needs the data structures defined in project A (and probably some functions as well).

I'm coming from a Go background where each module or package would have its own repo. For example, if both project A and project B had to read a particular file type, I would have a "file-reader" package in a separate repo. Is this the way to go with C++ as well?

Comment: The subject is too broad, unfortunately.

Comment: If A needs B and B needs A then it does not seem like there is a benefit of putting this stuff in separate repos since they are not decoupled - B will not be reusable from a fictional project C without it including A, too

Comment: You don't have two independent projects. You can factor out the shared parts into some library and then depend on that from both.

Comment: A needs B and B needs A, sounds like you should redesign your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your projects into shared libraries, and put the artifacts on Conan. Any executable would need the shared libraries from both project A, and Project B.  You can also add the circular dependency to Conan, so both project A and Project B will build (i.e.. Project A depends on B to build, and B depends on A).

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/

Comment: Just a note: Conan (and many other dependency managers) do not handle circular dependencies. The graph should be a directed, acyclic graph. It might be possible to have some special cases with ``build_requires``, because the dependencies are really different things, one is a package in the host context and another is another package in the build context, but still form a directed acyclic graph.